# Make opensuse 13.2 accept remote logging?

Tags: logs, opensuse, systemd, remote

My question is how can one make opensuse 13.2 accept remote logging?
Since it uses systemd-journal, which conflicts an installation attempt of syslog or rsyslog?
Many thanks!